# What is this style of webpack rule syntax: style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss

Tags: webpack

I am looking through the `create-react-app` webpack config and it contains the following code:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
},
```

I know that webpack loaders can be chained together by using an `!`, e.g. `style-loader!css-loader!less-loader`, but I am unfamiliar with the `?` syntax and everything that follows it. What exactly is it doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are query params
More here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters